Longtable row height limitation with rotated text
With the following code, I want to create a table that is rotated on the page, but the page itself is not rotated (it is for print in a book, so also the pdf cannot have rotated pages):
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\beginrotate}c<{\endrotate}}
\def\beginrotate{\begin{Sbox}}
\def\endrotate{\end{Sbox}\rotatebox{-90}{\TheSbox~~}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{\thepage}

\begin{longtable}{|RR|R|}
\caption{Exemplary long vertical table. \label{tab:label}}\\
\hline
Caption 3 & Caption 2 which is much longer than the other captions & Caption 1\\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Exemplary long vertical table (Continued).}
\endhead
Here is content of a cell which should be limited to 4 cm in row height. & Content & Content\\
Here is content of a cell which should be limited to 5 cm in row height. & Content & Content\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}

The table has a lot of columns, and will span over several pages. The first column should be repeated on each page. Also, the table has to have a caption on each page, but only the first one has a label, and on the next pages it is simply "continued".
I tried to build a workaround with a longtable, where I rotate the text in every field. But, I did not figure out how to restrict the height of each row.

Welcome to tex.sx.

your use case is basically what the lscape package landscape environment was designed for, it does not rotate the page, the page head and foot, page number position etc stay in portrait style but just the page body is rotated.

You are setting the text in a c column so after rotating it is exactly as high as the length of the text. What do you want to happen if the text is longer than 4cm? if it is long text it would normally be set in a p column that allows line breaking

I want it to behave as if it was a p column. So the text should do an automatic line break and the width of the column should be increased.
Using lscape, will the header, aka the first column, also be repeated on the next page?

no longtable will split on rows not columns but you could remove all the rotation within the table and rotate the whole page with the same effect if you want R ro be a p column just replace r by p{3cm} or whatever width you want i suspect your example isn't showing your real issue as it only have ttwo rows and three columns so would fit without any rotation at all and it's not clear whether you plan to extend columns or rows or both

That is, why not this output ?

Can you show an image (maybe hand-drawn) of what the table should look like?
